# Use Built In Soft Keyboard in Win 8 DirectX Metro App

Tags: input, keyboard, directx, windows-8, windows-runtime

Part of my app requires the user to enter text (username/password & chat) and I'd prefer not have to create my own keyboard code.

1. Is there a way to use the built in software keyboard for DirectX Metro Apps? I just need a way for touch users to enter text.
2. If it is possible, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if DirectX itself has something built-in, but you can [mix DirectX with XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh825871.aspx) - e.g. you could use [SwapChainBackgroundPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainbackgroundpanel.aspx) where all your DirectX rendering would occur and overlay a XAML TextBox where you would capture your text input.

Comment: I briefly looked over the links you provided. With that second link, are you essentially doing all your rendering with DirectX still and then rendering the Xaml component via DirectX, or is it the other way around?

Comment: I think it is up to you where you render most of the content. For XAML/DirectX interop there are three components and SwapChainBackgroundPanel is the one where you have full-screen DirectX content. The other ones are more for things like rendering XAML controls using DirectX - controls that are not necessarily full-screen.

Comment: Since I already have everything working using DirectX, I would want to use some system that would have minimal changes. So if there is some way to essentially render the XAML component necessary for this inside my existing DirectX code, that would be preferable. Otherwise I would just do it my self.

Comment: I don't think using SwapChainBackgroundPanel would require big changes to your DX code. I wish I had most of my code in DX - I'm only slowly getting into DX from the XAML world...

Comment: SharpDX is great! I had done some OpenGL and DirectX work before (w/ C++), but I love the SharpDX library.